# Why is $ \|T(x) \|\le \| T\| \|x \|$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces and let $T$ be a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$. The norm of $T$ is defined as
$$\|T \|=\sup\{\|T(x) \|\;:\;\|x \|\le 1\}. $$

From the definition of the norm, we can say that $\|T(x) \|\le \|T \|\;\forall \;x,$ and that $\|T \|\|x \|\le \|T \|$ as $\|x\|\le 1$.

However I don't understand why we write $\|T(x)\|\le \|T\|\|x\|$?

Comment: You can write \|T\| instead of \Vert T \Vert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly $\Vert T(x) \Vert \le \Vert T \Vert$ if $\Vert x \Vert = 1$.

Now, just remember that we're dealing with **linear** operators.

So if $\Vert x \Vert = c$, then $\Vert \frac{x}{c} \Vert = 1$.

So $$\left\Vert T(x) \right\Vert = c \left\Vert T\left(\frac{x}{c} \right) \right\Vert \le c \Vert T \Vert$$